# How do I improve this object design in Typescript?

Tags: object, design-patterns, typescript, functional-programming

I have created a class in Typescript that implements a simple stream (FRP). Now I want to extend it with client side functionality (streams of events). To illustrate my problem, here is some pseudo-code:

```
class Stream<T> {

    map<U>(f: (value: T) => U): Stream<U> {
        // Creates a new Stream instance that maps the values.
    }

    // Quite a few other functions that return new instances.

}
```

This class can be used both on the server and on the client. For the client side, I created a class that extends this one:

```
class ClientStream<T> extends Stream<T> {

    watch(events: string, selector: string): Stream<Event> {
        // Creates a new ClientStream instance
    } 

}
```

Now the `ClientStream` class knows about `map` but the `Stream` class doesn't know about `watch`. To circumvent this, functions call a factory method.

```
protected create<U>(.....): Stream<U> {
    return new Stream<U>(.....)
}
```

The `ClientStream` class overrides this function to return `ClientStream` instances. However, the compiler complains that `ClientStream.map` returns a `Stream`, not a `ClientStream`. That can be 'solved' using a cast, but besides being ugly it prevents chaining.

Example code that exhibits this problem:

```
class Stream {

    protected create(): Stream {
        return new Stream()
    }

    map() {
        return this.create()
    }

}

class ClientStream extends Stream {

    protected create(): ClientStream {
        return new ClientStream()
    }

    watch() {
        return this.create()
    }

}

let s = new ClientStream().map().watch()
```

This does not compile because according to the compiler, the stream returned from `map` is not a `ClientStream`: `error TS2339: Property 'watch' does not exist on type 'Stream'.`

I don't really like this pattern, but I have no other solution that is more elegant. Things I've thought about:

- Use composition (decorator). Not really an option given the number of methods I would have to proxy through. And I want to be able to add methods to `Stream` later without having to worry about `ClientStream`.
- Mix `Stream` into `ClientStream`. More or less the same problem, `ClientStream` has to know the signatures of the functions that are going to be mixed in (or not? Please tell).
- Merge these classes into one. This is a last resort, the `watch` function has no business being on the server.

Do you have a better (more elegant) solution? If you have an idea that gets closer to a more functional style, I'd be happy to hear about it. Thanks!

Comment: Can the factory methods be static? Or do they rely on instance data?

Comment: Yes, they could be static.

Comment: You can use the `polymorphic this types` as @SebastianSebald said, but your classes are generic which will make it harder.  I'm still trying to understand your problem though. Can you maybe update your code with an full example that shows the problem? Something I can just paste to playground and see what the error is and where.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow, thanks in advance for looking into it.

Comment: I don't understand your example. The `new ClientStream()` creates an instance then you invoke its `map()` method which creates a new instance of the same `ClientStream` class, and on that you invoke `watch()` which creates a new instance of `Stream` but `ClientStream` extends `Stream`. What is the point of all that? You had an instance of `ClientStream`/`Stream` with the first `new ClientStream()`.

Comment: The example is completely non-functional of course, I only included the code that demonstrate the problem. `map` returns a `ClientStream`, but the compiler thinks it returns a `Stream`. Thus, according to the compiler, I can't call `watch` on the stream returned from `map`. I can get it compiled with a cast. But that would mean that any code that uses methods defined in `ClientStream` would have to know this.

Comment: In the meantime I realized (also thanks to your comment regarding static methods) that chaining methods is actually the same as function composition (always learning). So I'm thinking of taking most methods out of the class (at least those that return a stream) and exporting them as functions and then combine things with a library like Ramda.

Comment: If you'd share your actual problem then I (or others) might better help you, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called [*F-bounded polymorphism*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/courses/819/f-bounded.pdf).

In TypeScript this is done via the `this` keyword. Take a look at Typescript's documentation for [**polymorphic this types**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types). If you follow the documentation, you should be able to implement what you want :-)

Actually, just make sure that you're returning `this` in your member methods and you should be fine!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could be wrong, but is this not just the builder pattern? There is mutable state involved here, which I'd like to prevent. The same goes for the extra `.currentValue()` call (typical for a builder).

Comment: I am not sure if this is the builder pattern. I looked it up on wikipedia and, too me, it looks like the builder pattern has something to do wie class inheritance. Correct me if I am wrong. Where do you see mutable state?

Comment: In the calculator example on the typescript site, `this.value` is modified for each calculation.

Comment: Regarding the builder pattern, it's a pattern where some product is constructed in several steps. In my opinion, this is what the calculator does. Even though it's 'just' a number, the result is still arrived at in multiple steps and has to be retrieved from the 'builder' with an extra method call (`currentValue`).

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. I would suggest to return a new instance then. So instead of `return this`, do `return new Stream`. What you want to do is very very similar to RxJS, maybe reading [this](https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87) will help also.